# Matrix of an orthogonal projector represented in the canonical basis

Tags: vector-spaces, projection-matrices

Find the matrix (represented in the canonical base $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$) of the projector $P:\mathbb{C^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{C^3}$ onto the subspace $$M=[\{f_1,f_2\}]=[\{(0,0,1),(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}},0)\}]$$
where the field is $\mathbb{C}$ so the dimension is $3$.

My attempt:

The basis for $M^{\perp}$ is $\{f_3\}=\{(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},0)\}$

Obviously, $(f)$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C^3}$.
Now I represent the canonical vectors $e_1,e_2$ and $e_3$ using this basis, but since I need to project them onto $M$ I only use the parts from vectors $f_1$ and $f_2$, or more specifically, the projection of a vector $x$ will be $$(x,f_1)f_1 + (x,f_2)f_2$$ where $(a,b)$ denotes the standard scalar product.

So, e.g. $$P(e_1)=(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}})\cdot f_2$$

Now, what I'm interested in is which basis I'm working in? Let us denote $A(c,d)$ where $A$ is a linear operator on $\mathbb{C}^3$ $c$ is a basis for the codomain and $d$ is a basis for the domain.

The matrix would be, after computing the projections of all canonical vectors:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1\\
    -2/5 & 1/5 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

meaning the projection of $e_2$ onto $M$ is $\frac{1}{5}f_2$ and for $e_3$ it's just $f_1$

Now, what I've got is $P(f,e)$, right?

I still need to compute $P(e,e)=I(e,f)*P(f,e)$ to get my final solution?

Comment: How did you go from $\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt5}\right)f_2$ to $(0,-2/5,0)^T$? The coordinates of $P(e_1)$ relative to the basis you’re calling $f$ are $(0,-2/\sqrt5,0)^T$.

Comment: Incidentally, the simplest way to produce the required matrix, given that you’ve already found a basis for $M^\perp$, (which, BTW, has a sign error), is to work out the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto that space—easy, because there’s only one vector to deal with—and then subtract that from the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ form an orthonormal basis, then, as you wrote,$$P(x)=\langle x,f_1\rangle f_1+\langle x,f_2\rangle f_2.$$So,$$P(e_1)=\frac2{\sqrt5}f_2=\left(\frac45,-\frac25,0\right),$$$$P(e_2)=-\frac1{\sqrt5}f_2=\left(-\frac25,\frac15,0\right),$$and$$P(e_3)=f_1=(0,0,1).$$Therefore, the matrix of $P$ with respect to the canonical basis is$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac45&-\frac25&0\\-\frac25&\frac15&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You started out reasonably, but then made some critical errors in constructing $P(f,e)$. You’d already stated earlier that $P(e_1)=-{2\over\sqrt5}f_2$ (which contains a sign error, by the way), i.e., that its coordinates in the $f$-basis are $\left(0,-2/\sqrt5,0\right)^T$, not $(0,-2/5,0)^T$. Similarly, $P(e_2)=-{1\over\sqrt5}f_2$, so the second column of the matrix should be $\left(0,-1/\sqrt5,0\right)^T$, not $(0,1/5,0)^T$. Using the correct matrix for $P(f,e)$ you should then get $$P(e,e) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & {2\over\sqrt5} & {1\over\sqrt5} \\ 0 & -{1\over\sqrt5} & {2\over\sqrt5} \\ 1&0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1 \\ {2\over\sqrt5} & -{1\over\sqrt5} & 0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac45 & -\frac25 & 0 \\ -\frac25 & \frac45 & 0 \\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Note, by the way, that you’ve also made a sign error computing a basis for $M^\perp$.